# Create a utility and send it via outlook for user to click and create a desk top shortcut and add a link in favourite

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, email, microsoft-outlook

I want to send an email via outlook to users, which has 2 options:

Option 1:

- Click this button to add this link to your browser's favorite section
- or click here for IE,
- click here for Firefox
- and click here for Chrome

Option 2:
Click this button to create a desktop shortcut. Shortcut of an internet page that will allow the user to click the shortcut and go straight on the link through the default browser.

Comment: No opera support? What about edge? Any way,  what did you try so far?

Comment: What you are trying to do is almost impossible. Not all email recipients use Outlook. How do you expect it to work in a webmail service like Google? In a text only email client like Agent? You would be better off sending the appropriate link with instructions for common email clients.

Comment: I am trying to look for starting point on how to create this.

Comment: The users I need to send this to all use outlook.

Comment: they however use IE, FireFox and Chrome as browsers

Comment: I understand your advise and appreciate it.. I have done that and now need to send this something like this..